# Vagga: Number of allowed subuids is too small

Tags: linux, linux-containers

I'm implementing [this simple vagga container example](http://vagga.readthedocs.org/en/latest/what_is_vagga.html) as part of their tutorial. When I try to run `vagga py3` I get:

> ERROR:vagga::wrapper: Error executing _build: Number of allowed subuids is too small. Required [Range { start: 0, end: 65536 }], allowed [Range { start: 0, end: 1 }, Range { start: 260000, end: 270000 }]. You either need to increase allowed numbers in /etc/subuid (preferred) or decrease needed ranges in vagga.yaml

I have never touched or even heard about subuids. I'm not sure why the example is not working out of the box. I also get a similar error for gids.

I have updated my `vagga.yaml`:

```
uids: [0-1]
gids: [0-1]
```

This actually works, but according to the error message this is not the preferred method. My user entry in `/etc/subuid` is:

```
ajcrites:260000:10000
```

Is there something that I need to do or can do to ensure that my `vagga.yaml` works out of the box on most systems including mine?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.

The best way to fix the issue is to edit your `/etc/subuid` to have at least `65536` users:

```
ajcrites:260000:65536
```

This is because most systems feel free to create users from `0` to `65535`. And also most systems that support user namespaces have `SUB_UID_COUNT 65536` in `/etc/login.defs` by default (same with subgids), which means new users will be created with a range of 65536 of subuids.

Changing `uids` and `gids` is fine too. But some future added packages can use additional user ids and may fail when installing.